# Make Text composable scrollable for Tv

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How do I make a Text composable scroll on D-PAD navigation for Tv?

```
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        Logger.d("the text is focused")

                    }
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .focusable()
                    .verticalScroll(scrollSState)

          LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
```

I do have a focus on the Text but it does not scroll.What I am doing wrong?

I was trying to scroll the content of the text when there is an overflow.Trying to achieve that on Tv devices which can handle D-pad navigation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can wrap it into a `Box` and make it scrollable like the following:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .height(50.dp)
        .width(50.dp)
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .focusable()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Your long text here",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
    )
}
```